# Export "Create Aggregate" functions from PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, pgadmin

I have created some user defined aggregate functions. However, I cannot see a way to export them in pgAdmin. Or any other way.

I can see the underlying functions, but not the `CREATE AGGREGATE` definitions.

SquirrelSQL doesn't show anything useful either!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably you need to enable the display of aggregates in your Options:
*File -> Options -> Browser -> Display*

After refreshing the view you get a separate node `Aggregates` in the object browser:

[image: Aggreagate node in object browser]

The reverse engineered `CREATE` script for the selected aggregate is displayed to the right in the SQL pane.

Comment: @w͏̢in̡͢g͘̕ed̨p̢͟a͞n͏͏t̡͜͝he̸r̴: I added another answer over there.