# How to get definition/source code of an aggregate in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, psql, ddl

I found this related answer useful:

- [Export "Create Aggregate" functions from PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112971/export-create-aggregate-functions-from-postgresql)

But how do I get the `CREATE AGGREGATE` statement without a GUI client (e.g. with psql command line)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, but I'm not sure if this covers all possible ways of creating an aggregate (it definitely does not take the need for quoted identifiers into account)

```
SELECT 'create aggregate '||n.nspname||'.'||p.proname||'('||format_type(a.aggtranstype, null)||') (sfunc = '||a.aggtransfn
       ||', stype = '||format_type(a.aggtranstype, null)
       ||case when op.oprname is null then '' else ', sortop = '||op.oprname end 
       ||case when a.agginitval is null then '' else ', initcond = '||a.agginitval end
       ||')' as source
FROM pg_proc p 
  JOIN pg_namespace n ON p.pronamespace = n.oid 
  JOIN pg_aggregate a ON a.aggfnoid = p.oid 
  LEFT JOIN pg_operator op ON op.oid = a.aggsortop 
where p.proname = 'your_aggregate'
  and n.nspname = 'public' --- replace with your schema name
```

Comment: Good start, but arguments should be something like `(SELECT string_agg(format_type(t, null), ', ') FROM unnest(p.proargtypes::oid[]) t)` -- see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d0e8a/2 -- also note that in PostgreSQL 9.4+ there are more options & types of custom aggregate functions.

Comment: Thanks guys. I thought there might be something similar to pg_get_functiondef but looks like no.

Comment: @pozs: Good point. There is also [`pg_get_function_identity_arguments()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) for this. Or more elegant, yet: `aggfnoid::regprocedure`. I added an updated version.

Answer (score 5):

A modern version to generate the `CREATE AGGREGATE` statement - using `format()` and casts to object identifier types to make it simple and add double-quotes and schema-qualification to identifiers where required automatically:

```sql
SELECT format('CREATE AGGREGATE %s (SFUNC = %s, STYPE = %s%s%s%s%s)'
            , aggfnoid::regprocedure
            , aggtransfn
            , aggtranstype::regtype
            , ', SORTOP = '    || NULLIF(aggsortop, 0)::regoper
            , ', INITCOND = '  || agginitval
            , ', FINALFUNC = ' || NULLIF(aggfinalfn, 0)
            , CASE WHEN aggfinalextra THEN ', FINALFUNC_EXTRA' END
            --  add more to cover special cases like moving-aggregate etc.
              ) AS ddl_agg
FROM   pg_aggregate
WHERE  aggfnoid = 'my_agg_func'::regproc;  -- name of agg func here
```

You can schema-qualify the aggregate function's name where necessary:

```
'public.my_agg_func'::regproc
```

And / or add function parameters to disambiguate in case of overloaded aggregate functions:

```
'array_agg(anyarray)'::regprocedure
```

This does not cover special cases like moving-aggregate functions etc. Can easily be extended to cover all options for your current Postgres version. But the next major version may bring new options.

A function *`pg_get_aggregatedef()`* similar to the existing [`pg_get_functiondef()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) would be great to eliminate the need for this custom query - which may have to be adapted with every new major Postgres version ...

Answer (score 1):

My version using some system functions

```
SELECT 
format(
   E'CREATE AGGREGATE %s (\n%s\n);'
   , (pg_identify_object('pg_proc'::regclass, aggfnoid, 0)).identity
   , array_to_string(
      ARRAY[
     format(E'\tSFUNC = %s', aggtransfn::regproc)
     , format(E'\tSTYPE = %s', format_type(aggtranstype, NULL))
     , CASE aggfinalfn WHEN '-'::regproc THEN NULL ELSE format(E'\tFINALFUNC = %s',aggfinalfn::text) END
     , CASE aggsortop WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE format(E'\tSORTOP = %s', oprname) END
     , CASE WHEN agginitval IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE format(E'\tINITCOND = %s', agginitval) END
      ]
      , E',\n'
   )
)

FROM pg_aggregate
LEFT JOIN pg_operator ON pg_operator.oid = aggsortop
WHERE aggfnoid = 'regr_r2'::regproc;
```